# Why can't I reach data within Method?

Tags: c#, winforms, delete-row

I'm currently trying to fill a `TableLayoutPanel` through a method which goes as follows:

```
private int _rowCount;
public void InitPaths()
{
    int c = 1;
    int a = 1;

    while (a < _PathRows.Length - 1)
    {
        var label = new Label();
        //
        // Label - Format.
        //
        label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        label.AutoSize = false;
        label.Text = _pfadZeilen[a];
        label.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(22, 13);
        label.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        TableLayoutP.Controls.Add(label, 3, c);

        //Checkboxen Einfügen
        var cbox = new CheckBox();
        //
        //Checkbox Format.
        cbox.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        cbox.AutoSize = true;
        cbox.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        cbox.Name = "checkBoxPfad" + a;
        cbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 14);
        cbox.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        cbox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        TableLayoutP.Controls.Add(cbox, 0, c);
        a++;
        c++;

    }

    this._rowCount = BibTable.GetRowHeights().Length; // which seems to be Holding the value only within the method
}
```

and then delete all rows on Action, through the following Method:

```
public void RemoveRows()
{
    for (int row = _rowCount; row >= 0; row--)
    {
        BibTable.RowStyles.RemoveAt(row);
        BibTable.RowCount--;
    }
}
```

Now the Problem is, if I try to do anything with the `TableLayoutP` outside of the method where all rows are initialized, it will tell me:

> Object reference not set to the instance of an object.

What can I do? Is there a way to get a method inside a method (I'm realising just how stupid that sounds while typing it) or any other way to deal with this Situation?

Comment: What is the relation between `TableLayoutP` and `BibTable`. I ask this because you initialize `TableLayoutP` and you delete from `BibTable`. I seems logicals if you add items to one collection, you cannot delete them from another.

Answer (score 0):

You are ittering through `GetRowHeights()`, returning the height of each row. But you are deleting from the `RowStyles` collection which is not directly related to the first collection. I assume that `GetRowHeights()` returns much more rows, than `RowStyles` has.

Why not:

```
BibTable.RowCount = 0;
BibTable.RowStyles.Clear();
```

Comment: Hi there Martin, thnx for your post,
the Thing is GetRowHeights().Length seems to be the only Thing that delivers the correct amount of rows (23 in this case) that i have, since im inserting them at runtime from a text data, but the BibTable.RowCount says ist only 6 rows (which is wrong)
A more Detailed Explanation is on the link below, thanks for your help!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375030/cant-reach-data-within-method-what-possibilities-are-there

Comment: What about property `RowCount`? He should hold the correct number of rows.

Comment: just tried it, RowCount tells = 6(false)and BibTable.GetRowHeights().Length = 23(correct)

Answer (score 0):

You are ittering through `GetRowHeights()`, returning the height of each row. But you are deleting from the `RowStyles` collection which is not directly related to the first collection. I assume that `GetRowHeights()` returns much more rows, than `RowStyles` has.

Why not:

```
BibTable.RowCount = 0;
BibTable.RowStyles.Clear();
```

Comment: Martin,
i came to use GetRowHeights() after i Did some Research on the above,
(see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ff7a4ba4-bf73-47c2-8689-fd93113fc31e)
it seens as though that is the only one that delivers the correct amount of Rows within a table, but the Real Problem seams to be something else, i can't delete the Rows Outside of my InitPaths () Method, what should i do in there?